# Flask application not showing up the new fields Python 3.9

Tags: python, flask

I am new to flask application. I am trying to create an application which reads data from an excel spreadsheet. The output in the app shows the fields as mentioned in the python script but when I try to add another field ("Therapeutic Area"), it does not show up in the app. I have modified the python script as well as index.html to include this column from a spreadsheet. PS: the code is written by someone as well and I am trying to add more columns from the spreadsheet to the the app.

Below is the snippet of python script and index.html

```
         for col in df.columns:
                pName = str(row[col])
                header = str(col)
                oheader = header
                if "Product Name" in header:
                    header = "Product Name"
                if "Company" in header:
                    header = "Company"
                if "Generic Name" in header:
                    header = "Generic Name"
                if "INN Name" in header:
                    header = "INN Name"
                if "Trade Name" in header:
                    header = "Trade Name"
                if "R&D N" in header or "R&D  N" in header:
                    header = "R&D Number"
                if "USAN" in header:
                    header = "USAN Name"
                if "Misc" in header:
                    header = "Synonyms"
                if "Synonym" in header:
                    header = "Synonyms"
                if "Status" in header:
                    header = "Status"
                if "Therapeutic Area" in header:
                    header = "Therapeutic Area"
                if "Active, Inactive" in header:
                    header = "Status"
                
                if not header == "Comments" and not header == "Type":
                    lname = str(pName)
                    if not lname == "nan" and not lname == "NaT":
                        if not tmp['section'][-1]['name']==header:
                            tmp['section'].append({'name':header, 'links':[]} )
                    #for se in tmp['section']:
                        se = tmp['section'][-1]
                        se['links'].append((lname,""))
```

```
<div class="row" hidden >
            <div class="col-4" > 
                
                <h3>Therapeutic Area</h3>
                    <ul id="Therapeutic Area" class="section"></ul>
                
                <h3>Name of company</h3>
                    <ul id="Company" class="section"></ul>
                
                <h3>Product Name</h3>
                    <ul id="Product Name" class="section"></ul>

                <h3>Type of Product</h3>
                    <ul id="Type of Product" class="section"></ul>

                <h3>Corporate ID</h3>
                    <ul id="Corporate ID" class="section"></ul>
                                        
                <h3>Synonyms</h3>
                    <ul id="Synonyms" class="section"></ul>
                        
                <h3>Status</h3>
                    <ul id="Status" class="section"></ul>
                    
            </div>
```

What could be the reason that after adding the new field to python script and index.html, it is not showing up in the app. Any help is highly appreciated.